# Mocking out React.Suspense Whilst Leaving the Rest of React Intact

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to write a [Jest](https://jestjs.io) unit test for a component that uses [React.Suspense](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#suspense).

Simplified versions of my component modules under test:

*MyComponent.js*

```
import React from 'react';

export default () => <h1>Tadaa!!!</h1>;
```

*MySuspendedComponent.js*

```
import React, { Suspense } from 'react';
import MyComponent from './MyComponent';

export default () => (
    <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading…</div>}>
        <MyComponent />
    </Suspense>
);
```

Naïvely, in my first attempt, I wrote a unit test that uses [Enzyme](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/) to mount the suspended component:

*MySuspendedComponent.test.js*

```
import React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import MySuspendedComponent from './MySuspendedComponent';

test('the suspended component renders correctly', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<MySuspendedComponent />);
    expect(wrapper.html()).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

This causes the test to crash with the error message:

> Error: Enzyme Internal Error: unknown node with tag 13

Searching for the error message on the web, I found that this is most likely caused by Enzyme not being ready to render `Suspense` (yet).

If I use `shallow` instead of `mount`, the error message changes to:

> Invariant Violation: ReactDOMServer does not yet support Suspense

My next attempt was to mock out `Suspense` with a dummy pass-through component, like this:

*MySuspendedComponent.test.js*

```
import React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import MySuspendedComponent from './MySuspendedComponent';

jest.mock('react', () => {
    const react = require.requireActual('react');
    return () => ({
        ...react,
        Suspense({ children }) {
            return children;
        }
    });
});

test('the suspended component renders correctly', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<MySuspendedComponent />);
    expect(wrapper.html()).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

The idea is to have a mock implementation of the React module that contains all the actual code from the React library, with only `Suspense` being replaced by a mock function.

I've used this pattern with `requireActual`, as described in the [Jest documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/bypassing-module-mocks), successfully in other unit tests when mocking other modules than React, but with React, it does not work.

The error I get now is:

> TypeError: (($_$w(...) , *react) || ($*$w(...) , _load_react(...))).default.createElement is not a function

…which, I assume, is caused by the original implementation of React not being available after my mocking trick.

**How can I mock out Suspense while leaving the rest of the React library intact?**

Or is there another, better way to test suspended components?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is not to use object spreading to export the original React module, but simply overwriting the `Suspense` property, like this:

*MySuspendedComponent.test.js*

```
import React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import MySuspendedComponent from './MySuspendedComponent';

jest.mock('react', () => {
    const React = jest.requireActual('react');
    React.Suspense = ({ children }) => children;
    return React;
});

test('the suspended component renders correctly', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<MySuspendedComponent />);
    expect(wrapper.html()).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

This creates the following snapshot, as expected:

*MySuspendedComponent.test.js.snap*

```
exports[`the suspended component renders correctly 1`] = `"<h1>Tadaa!!!</h1>"`;
```

Comment: Hey Patrick, if the child element passed to Suspense is another React component (instead of html tags), is there a way to preserve the `displayName` field of that component?

Comment: I am getting the error:
`Attempt to assign to const or readonly variable ` in `React.Suspense`

Answer (score 0):

I needed to test my lazy component using Enzyme. Following approach worked for me to test on component loading completion:

```
const myComponent = React.lazy(() => 
      import('@material-ui/icons')
      .then(module => ({ 
         default: module.KeyboardArrowRight 
      })
   )
);
```

Test Code ->

```
    //mock actual component inside suspense
    jest.mock("@material-ui/icons", () => { 
        return {
            KeyboardArrowRight: () => "KeyboardArrowRight",
    }
    });
    
    const lazyComponent = mount(<Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
               {<myComponent>}
           </Suspense>);
        
    const componentToTestLoaded  = await componentToTest.type._result; // to get actual component in suspense
        
    expect(componentToTestLoaded.text())`.toEqual("KeyboardArrowRight");
```

This is hacky but working well for Enzyme library.