# How to add unit tests in jest for dynamically loading components using react.lazy

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a component which is using react.lazy and suspense to dynamically render a component

Can someone please suggest how can we test this component using jest

```js
import React, { lazy, Suspense } from "react";

const Component2 = lazy(() => import("./Component2"));
class Component1 extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isClicked: false
    };
  }
  click = () => {
    this.setState({ isClicked: true });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>component1 </div>
        <button onClick={this.click}>get component2</button>
        {this.state.isClicked && (
          <Suspense fallback={<div>loading...</div>}>
            <Component2 />
          </Suspense>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Component1;
```

codesandbox link for that : https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-currying-ufxwb

Adding some tests here

```js
 import React from 'react';
import Enzyme, { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import Component1 from '../src/Component1.js';
Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() })
describe('MyComponent', () => {
  it('should render correctly i mode', () => {
    const component = shallow(<Component1 />);
    expect(component).toMatchSnapshot();
  });

  it('should not have component2', () => {
    const component = shallow(<Component1 />);
    expect(component.find('Component2').exists()).toEqual(true);
  })

  it('should contain button getComponent2 and should have component2', ()=> {
    const component = shallow(<Component1 />);
    expect(component.instance().state.isClicked).toEqual(false);
    expect(component.find('button').exists());
    const button = component.find('button');
    button.simulate("click");
    expect(component.instance().state.isClicked).toEqual(true);
    expect(component.find('Component2').exists()).toEqual(true);
 
  });  

});
```

In this example Component2 is dynamically rendered and lazily loaded
i tried to write tests for that
const button = component.find('button');
    button.simulate("click");
    expect(component.instance().state.isClicked).toEqual(true);
    expect(component.find('Component2').exists()).toEqual(true);

as the above ,but the tests are not successful
Please suggest how can we do it with jest and enzyme

Comment: could you add also some test template/renderer library to get ready-to-start playground? I believe dynamic import returns a promise and `lazy()` just focus on `'default'` key of the object that promise will be resolved with. and to test different cases we need to use `jest.doMock` with factory that returns such a Promise. but have not checked idea with a code yet

Comment: tricky idea is to replace actual `lazy()` with deadly simple "just return a component": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54010426/mocking-out-react-suspense-whilst-leaving-the-rest-of-react-intact

Comment: oh, great, seems `enzyme` provided explicit support for this feature recently: https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/pull/1975 (in case you use Enzyme)

Comment: ya i do ... i dont see any solution being mentioned in the thread you gave.

Comment: i just tried to do mount(<Component1/>) , it fails on jest

Comment: this is how i planned to test itit('should contain button getComponent2 and should have component2', ()=> {
    const component = shallow(<Component1 />);
    expect(component.instance().state.isClicked).toEqual(false);
    expect(component.find('button').exists());
    const button = component.find('button');
    button.simulate("click");
    expect(component.instance().state.isClicked).toEqual(true);
    expect(component.find('Component2').exists()).toEqual(true);
    expect(component.find('.component-2').exists()).toEqual(true);
  });

Comment: sorry, missed your previous comment. from thread in `enzyme` repo there is mentioned that supporting `suspense` landed in 3.10.0. but as far as I see with passing `suspenseFallback` into [`shallow()`](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/shallow.html) we just force all lazy components to display fallback...

Comment: but it was also mentioned how to mock lazy components: https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/pull/1975#discussion_r248163915 but trying that locally I was unable to get test succeeding :(

Comment: found one! https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14577#issuecomment-455835299 but did not tried it yet.

Comment: spent some time trying that and this, and finally feeling like it's a bug as for Enzyme  3.10. It did not work to me either with `shallow()` or with `mount()`.  After searching there I've found open bugs https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/2200 and https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/2212